# How do I reference a path stored in the registry?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2008, reference, registry, environment-variables

How do I insert a string stored as a REG_SZ in the registry into a path? What I am trying to do is set .csproj references to a predefined path in our registry, but when I search all I am seeing is how the %PATH% env variable is stored in the registry. Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
<Reference Include="Interop.SienaASAP2, Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89a52a4f35bb97a3, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Bin\Interop.SienaASAP2.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Where the "..\..\..\" are, I would like to, for instance, insert the path at [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MyCompany\DefaultVersion\Folder]. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify you want to open a Project and have Visual-Studio resolve a referenced dll using a path stored in a registry value?

Comment: Yes. I've dodged the issue so far by including detailed instructions for how to set a reference path using Visual Studio for our end-users to follow, but I would rather have it able to build by having our clients just hit Rebuild Solution.

Comment: Here is an update; I had our installer create a registry value in [HKCU\Environment] so that the next time the machine is rebooted, you can reference the path in Explorer via %MxVDefaultPath%. The problem is, Visual Studio doesn't seem to honor this variable when I replace "..\..\..\" with "%MxVDefaultPath%\" (though I have verified that the variable does indeed work when referencing it in cmd or Explorer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using out of the box behavior you can't have visual studio use HintPath by referencing a Environment variable.

This is how Visual Studio resovles the references form this [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817675.aspx)

> At build time, Visual Studio .NET
>   resolves assembly references by
>   searching the following locations in
>   the following order:
>
> 1. Look for the assembly in one of the project folders. This assumes that you
>      have added the assembly to the project
>      by using the Add Existing Item menu
>      option. Project folders include any
>      folder displayed by Solution Explorer
>      (except when Show All Files is in
>      effect).
> 2. Look in the folders listed in the ReferencePath attribute of the
>       element within the project
>      user options file. This attribute can
>      contain a comma delimited list of
>      folders.
> 3. Use the`<HintPath>`element in
>      the project file.
> 4. Look in a set of folders identified by registry settings. These are the
>      ones that contain assemblies displayed
>      on the .NET tab of the Add references
>      dialog box. For more details, see
>      Using the .NET Tab of the Add
>      Reference Dialog Box.
> 5. Look for COM Interop assemblies in the obj sub folder beneath the project
>      folder. For more details, see
>      Referencing COM Objects.

However that fourth option may help you just add your paths to one of these registry keys and then it will work without messing with HintPath

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework\AssemblyFolders
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework\AssemblyFolders
```